# Type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean

I am new to flutter and don't know how to solve this. When decoding a bool from json type (coming from database) it works just fine at first, but turns to null later. A attack a code and debug console's errors.

```
Future<void> fetchProducts() async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://recipier-e1139-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/recipes.json');
    final favUrl = Uri.parse(
        'https://recipier-e1139-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/usersFavorites/$userId.json');
    try {
      final favResponse = await http.get(favUrl);
      final favStatus = json.decode(favResponse.body); 
      final response = await http.get(url);
      print(favStatus);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (extractedData.isEmpty || extractedData['error'] != null) {
        return;
      }
      List<Recipe> loadedRecipes = [];
      extractedData.forEach(
        (id, data) {
          print(favStatus[id]);
          loadedRecipes.add(
            Recipe(
              title: data['title'],
              description: data['description'],
              id: id,
              ingredients: data['ingredients'].cast<String>(),
              steps: data['steps'].cast<String>(),
              kcal: double.parse(data['kcal'].toString()).toInt(),
              p: double.parse(data['p'].toString()).toInt(),
              c: double.parse(data['c'].toString()).toInt(),
              f: double.parse(data['f'].toString()).toInt(),
              servings: double.parse(data['servings'].toString()).toInt(),
              favorite: favStatus == null ? false : favStatus[id] ?? false,
            ),
          );
        },
      );
      _recipes = loadedRecipes;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }



Future<void> selectFavorite(String userId) async {
    final bool oldStatus = favorite;
    favorite = !favorite;
    notifyListeners();
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://recipier-e1139-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/usersFavorites/$userId/$id.json');
    try {
      final response = await http.put(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'favoriteStatus': favorite,
          },
        ),
      );
      if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
        restoreFavStatus(oldStatus);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      restoreFavStatus(oldStatus);
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

> I/flutter ( 5416): {-Mvmce_36k5ksc0Aj1Il: {favoriteStatus: true},
> -MvrBKT3FQipzVFOK1q-: {favoriteStatus: true}} I/flutter ( 5416): null I/flutter ( 5416): {favoriteStatus: true} E/flutter ( 5416):
> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type
> '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type
> 'bool' E/flutter ( 5416): #0
> RecipeProvider.fetchProducts.
> package:recipier/providers/recipes_provider.dart:52 E/flutter ( 5416):
> #1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:539:8) E/flutter ( 5416): #2
> RecipeProvider.fetchProducts

Answer (score 0):

This happens when one of the entries has a null value or empty map instead of the boolean value. Can you check/send the response json?

Comment: I/flutter (17683): {"-Mvmce_36k5ksc0Aj1Il":{"favoriteStatus":true},"-MvrBKT3FQipzVFOK1q-":{"favoriteStatus":true}} - this is response.body